# Serve different robots.txt based on HTTP_HOST

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two sites both being indexed by google using the same codebase:

dev.mysite.com and example.com

I want to serve a different robots.txt based on each domain.

Currently I have:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots\.txt\.dev [L]
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

For me worked following by adding extra condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mysite\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (robots\.txt)
RewriteRule .* robots-dev.txt [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way for multiple domains on same server

htaccess file

```
#load php file named robot.php on root folder
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ "\/robots.php" [L]
```

php file robot.php

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    // default path  
    $path = "./robots.txt";
    
    if ( preg_match("/domainname_one/i",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ) {
        $path = "./domainname_one_folder/robots.txt";
    }
    if ( preg_match("/domainname_two/i",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ) {
        $path = "./domainname_two_folder/robots.txt";
    }
    if ( preg_match("/domainname_three/i",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ) {
        $path = "./domainname_two_folder/robots.txt";
    }
    echo file_get_contents( $path );
?>
```